# How do I add (IntelliSense) parameter comments for a method in C#

Tags: c#, .net, intellisense

When I use any .NET methods, there is a little hint (IntelliSense) which explains the methods and their parameters.

How do I achieve the same behaviour for my own methods?

Is there a Visual Studio feature which allows me to add these in?

Comment: As Reniuz said below. Consider GhostDoc. Great tool. Gets you in the habit of using good method names so that the tool can create meaningful comments.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

the "feature" is called **XML comments**. Just type /// right before your methods and VS will generate some xml tags. These will be used to show the tooltip as well as parameter info aso.

```
/// <summary>
/// this will be the tooltip
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args">args will be passed when starting this program</param>
static void Main(string[] args)
{

}
```

Screenshot of my **VS2010** when calling method *add*. As you can see, xml comments are shown.
[image: Screenshot of my VS2010 when calling method ADD]

Comment: One other point, I've tried this out, but nowhere does the hint show in intellisense (the yellow hint box). Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.  Why is it the simple things are the hardest to get working?!? Tried checking the XML doc file in the build tab but no luck still. argh!

Comment: Did some research: You may try resetting your setting in vs. What version of vs do you use? On the other hand, perhaps it's just the brackets missing - try to write: "add(" after writing the "(" the tooltip should show up!

Comment: Must be a bug in visual studio?? I'm using the following: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

Comment: try to reset all your settings - extras - options - import / export settings - this starts a wizard - and there you may reset all setting

Answer (score 13):

Yes you can. Heres an example:

```
/// <summary>
/// My super method
/// </summary>
/// <param name="myNumber">My number parameter</param>
/// <returns>My result</returns>
private int myMethod(int myNumber)
{
   return myNumber
}
```

To automatically generate xml comment just type `///` above your method, property, class, etc. And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx) is recommended tags for documentation. Also you can use [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) to simplify your documentation duty.

Answer (score 6):

It's called [XML documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx). You have to write the following comments above your method signature:

```
/// <summary>
/// Performs a custom action: ...
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x">
/// An integer representing the ...
/// </param>
/// <param name="y">
/// A boolean representing the ...
/// </param>
public void MyMethod(int x, bool y) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You Need xml comments like this

```
///<summary>my Description</summary>
public void mymethod()
```

Like described on msdn
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can do bay adding a special comment to your function (Mind the 3 slashes) Here is a short example:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// This is my special function
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="myParameter">Very important parameter.</param>
 /// <returns>Always returns 42.</returns>
 public int MyFunction(string myParameter)
 {
       return 42;
 }
```

Explanation:
**<< summary >>** Is the tag for to explain the functionality

**<< param name="" >>** Explains one paremter

**<< returns >>** The tag for the explanation of the retunr value.

There are several more tags, whoch Visual Studio will show you, when you edit that comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you press forward slash three times when above your method/property visual studio will generate an XML comments summary which you can then populate with the relevant info.

Another good tip is that if you go to project properties and then the Build tab you will see towards the bottom there is am Output section. If you tick the XML documentation file each time your project is built an XML file for your API will be generated alongside the dll which is great for other developers consuming your API.  This also means that visual studio will raise warnings for any public member that is not yet commented or commented incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. It's Xml documentation [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx)